# Сохранить CSV / DataFrame в Excel с автоматическим заданием ширины столбцов, автофильтром столбцов и т.д

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, форматирование

Появилась необходимость автоматически конвертировать CSV в Excel так, чтобы автоматически задавалась соответствующая ширина столбцов, автоматически устанавливались "автофильтры" столбцов и автоматически замораживалась верхняя строка с наименованием столбцов и т.д.

Решение с использованием модуля Pandas, которое конвертирует CSV файл в Excel формат:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_csv("filename.csv").to_excel("filename.xlsx", index=False)
```

**Вопрос:** но как быть с автоматическими "автофильтрами", шириной  столбцов, адаптированной под ширину данных или ширину имени столбца, и замораживанием строки с именами столбцов?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

После очередного обновления модулей перестала работать [версия, основанная на `XlsxWriter`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1098849/211923), поэтому решил переписать эту же функцию с использованием `openpyxl`:

```
def df_to_excel_auto_fmt(
        df,
        fn,
        max_col_width=30,
        autofilter=True,
        freeze_panes=(1, 0),
        fmt_int="#,##0",
        fmt_float="#,##0.00",
        fmt_date="yyyy-mm-dd",
        fmt_datetime="yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss",
        **kwargs):
    """
    Export / save Pandas.DataFrame to an Excel file with automatically adjusted column's widths.
    It can also add Excel column "autofilters" and freeze panes (top rows and left columns).
    Cell values will be formatted according to "fmt_*" parameters.

    :param df: DataFrame to be exported to Excel
    :param fn: output Excelfile name. NOTE: the extension will be changed to ".xlsx"
    :param max_col_width: maximum column width in Excel. Default: 30
    :param autofilter: boolean - whether add Excel autofilter or not. Default: True
    :param freeze_panes: tuple of int (length 2).
                         Specifies the one-based bottommost row and rightmost column
                         that is to be frozen.
    :param fmt_int: Excel format for integer numbers
    :param fmt_float: Excel format for float numbers
    :param fmt_date: Excel format for dates
    :param fmt_datetime: Excel format for datetime's
    :param kwargs: additional arguments to pass to df.to_excel(filename, **kwargs)
    :return:  None

    (c) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/211923/maxu?tab=profile
    """
    from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

    def set_column_format(ws, column_letter, fmt):
        for cell in ws[column_letter]:
            cell.number_format = fmt
    file = Path(fn).with_suffix(".xlsx")
    # get default parameters
    first_col = int(kwargs.get("index", True)) + 1
    sheet_name = kwargs.get("sheet_name", "Sheet1")
    if "freeze_panes" not in kwargs:
        kwargs["freeze_panes"] = freeze_panes
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(
        file.with_suffix(".xlsx"),
        engine="openpyxl",
        date_format=fmt_date,
        datetime_format=fmt_datetime)
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, **kwargs)
    # workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet_name]
    for xl_col_no, dtyp in enumerate(df.dtypes, first_col):
        col_no = xl_col_no - first_col
        width = max(df.iloc[:, col_no].astype(str).str.len().max(),
                    len(df.columns[col_no]) + 6)
        width = min(max_col_width, width)
        # print(f"column: [{df.columns[col_no]} ({dtyp.name})]\twidth:\t[{width}]")
        column_letter = get_column_letter(xl_col_no)
        worksheet.column_dimensions[column_letter].width = width
        if np.issubdtype(dtyp, np.integer):
            set_column_format(worksheet, column_letter, fmt_int)
        if np.issubdtype(dtyp, np.floating):
            set_column_format(worksheet, column_letter, fmt_float)
    if autofilter:
        worksheet.auto_filter.ref = worksheet.dimensions
    writer.save()
    writer.close()
```

---

Пример использования:

```
fn = r"c:\download\file.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(fn, sep=";")
df_to_excel_auto_fmt(
    df,
    fn,
    max_col_width=30,
    fmt_datetime="dd.mm.yy hh:mm",
    index=False)
```

Answer (score 4):

Приведенная ниже функция позволяет автоматически устанавливать "автофильтры" столбцов, адаптировать ширину столбцов под ширину данных или ширину имени столбца и "замораживать" верхние строки и/или левые столбцы:

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd


def df_to_excel_auto_fmt(
        df,
        fn,
        max_col_width=30,
        autofilter=True,
        freeze_panes=(1, 0),
        fmt_int="#,##0",
        fmt_float="#,##0.00", 
        fmt_date="yyyy-mm-dd",
        fmt_datetime="yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss",
        **kwargs):
    """
    Export / save Pandas.DataFrame to an Excel file with automatically adjusted column's widths.
    It can also add Excel column "autofilters" and freeze panes (top rows and left columns).
    Cell values will be formatted according to "fmt_*" parameters.

    :param df: DataFrame to be exported to Excel
    :param fn: output Excelfile name. NOTE: the extension will be changed to ".xlsx"
    :param max_col_width: maximum column width in Excel. Default: 30
    :param autofilter: boolean - whether add Excel autofilter or not. Default: True
    :param freeze_panes: tuple of int (length 2).
                         Specifies the one-based bottommost row and rightmost column
                         that is to be frozen.
    :param fmt_int: Excel format for integer numbers
    :param fmt_float: Excel format for float numbers
    :param fmt_date: Excel format for dates
    :param fmt_datetime: Excel format for datetime's
    :param kwargs: additional arguments to pass to df.to_excel(filename, **kwargs)
    :return:  None
    """
    file = Path(fn).with_suffix(".xlsx")
    # get default parameters
    first_col = int(kwargs.get("index", True))
    sheet_name = kwargs.get("sheet_name", "Sheet1")
    if "freeze_panes" not in kwargs:
        kwargs["freeze_panes"] = freeze_panes
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(
        file.with_suffix(".xlsx"), 
        engine="xlsxwriter",
        date_format=fmt_date,
        datetime_format=fmt_datetime)
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, **kwargs)
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet_name]
    int_fmt = workbook.add_format({'num_format': fmt_int})
    float_fmt = workbook.add_format({'num_format': fmt_float})
    for xl_col_no, dtyp in enumerate(df.dtypes, first_col):
        col_no = xl_col_no - first_col
        width = max(df.iloc[:, col_no].astype(str).str.len().max(), 
                    len(df.columns[col_no]) + 6)
        width = min(max_col_width, width)
        # print(f"column: [{df.columns[col_no]}]\twidth:\t[{width}]")
        if np.issubdtype(dtyp, np.integer):
            worksheet.set_column(xl_col_no, xl_col_no, width, int_fmt)
        elif np.issubdtype(dtyp, np.floating):
            worksheet.set_column(xl_col_no, xl_col_no, width, float_fmt)
        else:
            worksheet.set_column(xl_col_no, xl_col_no, width)
    if autofilter:
        worksheet.autofilter(0, 0, 0, df.shape[1] + first_col)
    writer.save()
    writer.close()
```

---

Пример использования:

```
fn = r"c:\download\file.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(fn, sep=";")
df_to_excel_auto_fmt(
    df,
    fn,
    max_col_width=30,
    fmt_datetime="dd.mm.yy hh:mm",
    index=False)
```

Comment: А как адаптировать этот код к форматированию ексель документа с несколькими вкладками? Сейчас оно правильно форматирует 1 вкладку, а остальные удаляет.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю,можно ли здесь спрашивать по ошибкам... но у меня что-то ошибка при попытке попробовать код

```
NameError: name 'np' is not defined
```

С этим разобрался - импорт библиотеки. Так же выяснил, что код выдаёт ошибку из-за устаревшего параметра

```
writer.save()
```

Удалил, оставив writer.close()  и всё заработало!

Answer (score 0):

Раз этот вопрос первый в гугле по запросу "автоширина столбца excel pandas" то напишу ответ сюда. Предложенные методы автофита возможно скоро перестанут работать, вот что пишет разработчик:

```
FutureWarning: save is not part of the public API, usage can give unexpected results and will be removed in a future version
  writer.save()
```

К тому же они громоздкие и `сложные` для понимания.

Вот то, что решит вашу проблему автофита столбцов в `3 строки`:

```
from UliPlot.XLSX import auto_adjust_xlsx_column_width

with pd.ExcelWriter("example.xlsx") as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="MySheet")
    auto_adjust_xlsx_column_width(df, writer, sheet_name="MySheet", margin=1)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]