# Не меняется дата в формат даты с точкой как разделитель

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Почему не меняются даты в формат даты с точкой?

Пользуюсь вот таким методом:

```
portfel['Дата поворота'] = pd.to_datetime(portfel['Дата поворота'], format = "%Y.%m.%d")
```

Возращает как даты, но через дефис, вот так: `%Y-%m-%d`. И игнорирует параметр `unit`

Есть еще стандартный для строк, он работает как надо, но не для DataFrame.

Вход:

```
96       2020-06-17
131      2020-06-19
139      2020-04-08
144      2020-06-26
145      2020-05-22
106328   2020-04-24
106330   2020-04-14
106365   2020-03-31
106376   2020-04-02
106432   2020-03-30
```

Выход:

```
96       2020.06.17
131      2020.06.19
139      2020.04.08
144      2020.06.26
145      2020.05.22
106328   2020.04.24
106330   2020.04.14
106365   2020.03.31
106376   2020.04.02
106432   2020.03.30
```

Может я не правильно понимаю концепцию дат в Phyton? На VB к примеру я могу указать формат в котором будет отоброжаться дата (через точку, пробел, тире и т.п.), но ее формат все равно будет датой. Я хочу что-бы даты оставались датами, но через точку.

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста суть вопроса. Что именно вы хотите получить на выходе?

Comment: Метод pd.to_datetime() преобразовывает строковые значения в тип данных: datetime

Comment: хочу получить столбец в котором даты записанны в формате ("27.03.2020").

Comment: Т.е. тип данных  в результирующем столбце должен быть строковой? Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшие примеры входных и выходных данных.

Comment: @MaxU дополнил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
portfel['Дата поворота'] = portfel['Дата поворота'].dt.strftime("%Y.%m.%d")
```

Учтите что после данного преобразования вы не сможете работать с данными как с датами - теперь это строки.

Comment: спасибо, снова выручили, но вопрос. Теперь столбец получил тип object. Как лучше поступить? Я делаю срез временной по столбцу с датами, потом выгружаю его в excel. Лучше сразу сделать формат с точками и с ним манипулировать. Или преобразовать формат в datetime, провести нужные манипуляции, а только перед выгрузкой поменять формат.

Comment: @Argo7, воспользуйтесь [этой функцией](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1098849/211923) ;)

Answer (score 2):

Отвечаю на вопрос из [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1100450/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b2-pandas/1100512#comment1896307_1100472):

> Как лучше поступить? Я делаю срез временной по столбцу с датами, потом
>   выгружаю его в excel. Лучше сразу сделать формат с точками и с ним
>   манипулировать. Или преобразовать формат в datetime, провести нужные
>   манипуляции, а только перед выгрузкой поменять формат.

Рекомендую воспользоваться функцией [to_excel_auto_fmt()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1098849/211923) для правильного форматирования дат.
Данная функция позволяет форматировать данные непосредственно в Excel файле, поэтому на вход ей подается DataFrame с "родными" типами данных - (`int`, `float`, `datetime`, etc.).

Пример:

```
to_excel_auto_fmt(
        df,
        "/path/to/file.xlsx", 
        max_col_width=30,
        autofilter=True,
        freeze_top_rows=1,
        fmt_int="#,##0", 
        fmt_float="#,##0.00", 
        fmt_date="yyyy.mm.dd",
        fmt_datetime="yyyy.mm.dd hh:mm:ss")
```