# Python модуль win32com.client. Для работы модуля нужен офис на машине?

Tags: python, openpyxl, pywin32

Работаю с ***pandas***. Для форматирования результирующих таблиц для человеческого глаза использую модуль
***win32com***. Все работает. Вопрос - должен ли на машине, где будет работать программа, стоять офис, конкретно эксель? 
Для конкретности - кусочек примера форматирования.

```
import win32com.client
Excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
wb = Excel.Workbooks.Open("E:\\OneDrive\\..\\Trade_snapshot_.xlsx")

# REC sheet formating
ws_rec = wb.Worksheets("Sheet01")
to_color = ("01_", '10_', '20_')
for seached in to_color:
    ws_rec.Cells.Find(seached).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
ws_rec.Rows('1:1').WrapText = True
# 
ws_rec.Columns('B:AZ').ColumnWidth = 9.71
ws_rec.Rows("1:1").EntireRow.AutoFit

ws_rec.Range("B2").Select
wb.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
ws_rec.Save
```

как мне кажется, ***openpyxl*** не в состоянии сделать такое форматирование.
Например *FreezePanes* - для активного окна, а в документации даже нет такого раздела...
Итого два вопроса:
1) для работы (скажем в интернете) нужен ли на машине установлен Excel / Windows
2) можно ли это переписать на ***openpyxl***

---

P.S.:  Первый вопрос отпал.
*pywin32*, в которой живет *win32com* - только винда. Посему остается вторая часть. Как реализую  -  приведу код решения.
...

Comment: [связанный вопрос...](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1098848/%d0%a1%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-csv-dataframe-%d0%b2-excel-%d1%81-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b1%d1%86%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82)

Comment: [AutoFit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197574/openpyxl-adjust-column-width-size), [WrapText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42215933/apply-wrap-text-to-all-cells-using-openpyxl)

Comment: спасибо, я даже нашел как зафризить панель.
Но блин - только косвенное упоминание в документации ))

`c = ws['B2']    
 ws.freeze_panes = c `
...
но форматировать надо каждую ячейку в цикле. Это жесть

Comment: @MaxU
Можете ответить -  win32com только для Windows машин, плюс Excell на машине?
Пока не хочется на openpyxl 
переходить ))

Comment: [раскрашивать ячейки можно при помощи Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html) ;) А по каким критериям вам надо раскрашивать? Вы можете выложить на какой-нибудь файлообменник небольшой пример входных данных и то, что хотите получить на выходе (в виде Excel файлов)?

Comment: @MaxU
ситуация такая - столбцы в таблице не все появляются. некоторые то есть то нет. В полученной таблице надо найти название столбца и покрасить его.
Вот прям как в коде программы )
А статья прикольная. Не знал.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107187/discussion-between-vasyl-kolomiets-and-maxu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рабочий пример:

```
import re
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Color, PatternFill, Font, Border

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=(20, 15)))
df.columns = [f"{col:02d}_col" for col in df.columns]
filename = r"c:\temp\test.xlsx"

# function definition: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1098849/211923
df_to_excel_auto_fmt(df, filename, max_col_width=15, index=False)

def fill_conditionally(
        filename, search_regex, fill_color=None,
        min_row=1, max_row=None, min_col=1, max_col=None):
    if fill_color is None:
        fill_color = PatternFill(start_color='EE1111',
                                   end_color='EE1111',
                                   fill_type='solid')
    if isinstance(fill_color, str):
        fill_color = PatternFill(start_color=fill_color,
                                   end_color=fill_color,
                                   fill_type='solid')
    wb = load_workbook(filename)
    ws = wb.active
    for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=min_row, max_row=max_row,
                            min_col=min_col, max_col=max_col):
        for cell in row:
            if re.search(search_pat, str(cell.value)):
                cell.fill = fill_color

    wb.save(filename)
    wb.close()

search_strings = ("01_", "05_", "10_")
search_pat = r"^(?:{})".format("|".join(search_strings))

fill_color = "CCFFFF"

fill_conditionally(
    filename=filename,
    search_regex=search_pat,
    fill_color=fill_color,
    min_row=1,
    max_row=1)
```

---

результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: супер!
Благодарю!

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, был рад помочь) да и задача показалась мне интересной

Comment: !
А нет ли под рукой ссылки на номера цветов в экселе для win32com?

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html#indexed-colours ? Для win32com - надо гуглить)

Comment: вот бедный вариант )
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.colorindex